# DynamoDB - Batch Update only if Partition Key and Range Key exists

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a use case where I have to batch update a certain number of items in DynamoDB Table with the condition "Partition Key" and "Range Key" exists.
If they do not exists, I do not have to update the item.

My current fields are - partitionkeyfield, rangekeyfield, fieldForUpdate, Randomkey1, RandomKey2.

I know that "ConditionExpression can be employed for UpdateItem but is there a similar approach for this in BatchUpdate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The partiQL batchExecuteStatement allows conditional writes of multiple items. The regular API does not allow conditional batch writes

Comment: do you have a link resource for this?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchExecuteStatement.html and https://twitter.com/pete_aws/status/1445583192954605568